# The error " Cannot resolve method 'println(void)' " is displayed when calling a method in System.out.println

Tags: java, object, intellij-idea, methods, equals

The Person class:

```
public class Person {

    public Person() { }

    public void isTheSamePerson (Person p){
       if (p.equals(p)) {
           System.out.println("They have the same names !!!");
       } else{
           System.out.println("They have different names !!!");
       }
    }
}
```

The Driver class:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person Persona1 = new Person();
        Person Persona2 = new Person();
        System.out.print(Persona1.isTheSamePerson(Persona2));
    }
}
```

When 
I am trying to Call the method `isTheSamePerson()` in a `System.out.println()`. I get the error "Cannot resolve method 'println(void)' "

Comment: isTheSamePerson method return nothing so println method cannot be called with.

Comment: print wants a string, you pass to the function the result of the method isTheSamePerson, which is void. The error is saying you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Couple things are off in your code here... First and foremost like the other comment said you should not call the method inside of a system.out.println since it's already going to be printing the result inside the method.

The second thing that's off is your equal comparator.

```
  if (p.equals(p)) {
```

You're comparing the object against itself which is wrong. You probably want to compare the instance of the object, and it looks like you're trying to compare the names so maybe something like

```
if(this.name.equals(p.getName())){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`isTheSamePerson()` method has void as return type.

However, `System.out.print()` expects an object of Type String.

Also, `isTheSamePerson()` always prints the same message since it takes only one `Person` and compares it against itself.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to call it inside println method

Instead of 
System.out.print(Persona1.isTheSamePerson(Persona2));

Write 
Persona1.isTheSamePerson(Persona2);

And you should get expected output.